# Similarity of block diagonal matrices

Tags: block-matrices, matrix-analysis

Let M and N be block diagonal matrices with the same size and partition

If M ~ N , then there exist an invertible matrix S such that 
MS = SN.

My question is, does S is also block diagonal matrix ?

If yes, and  $$ M = Diag(M_1, M_2, ..., M_n) $$ and
 $$ N = Diag(N_1, N_2, ..., N_n) $$
does it mean that  M_i ~ N_i  for all i ?

Comment: Nope. Even if the blocks are $1 \times 1$, this is false.

Comment: Im confused, why ? Can you give a counter example ?

Comment: $\operatorname{diag}\left(1,2\right)$ and $\operatorname{diag}\left(2,1\right)$ are similar, but not by a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Ohh . Tnk so much